# Can't get wild card query to work on multiple fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get wild card to work on multiple fields in elastic search but it doesn't seem to work. When I use this it just returns result that is same as submitting an empty query. Here is my query :

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "ratingCount": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "avgRating": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": 20,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstName": "Mich*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "lastName": "Mich*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your mapping look like and can you post an example document?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `from` property is your problem? Take a look on the [From/Size documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-from-size.html). From 20 means that the offset from the first result is 20. This means that you need to have at least 21 results overall to see one record in your query.

Take a look on example. First put three records:

```
PUT index/_doc/1
{
  "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
  "firstName": "Michael",
  "lastName": "Jordan"
}

PUT index/_doc/2
{
  "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
  "firstName": "Tomasz",
  "lastName": "Michalowicz"
}

PUT index/_doc/3
{
  "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
  "firstName": "Bartosz",
  "lastName": "Michalski"
}
```

And then search with your query and `from` set to 3:

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 3,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstName": "Mich*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "lastName": "Mich*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response will be:

```
{
  "took": 15,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

You can see that there is no visible `hits` but `total` is equal to 3.

Then change `from` to 2 and query again:

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 2,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstName": "Mich*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "lastName": "Mich*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The answer is:

```
{
  "took": 13,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
          "firstName": "Bartosz",
          "lastName": "Michalski"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then change `from` to 0 and query again:

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstName": "Mich*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "lastName": "Mich*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
          "firstName": "Tomasz",
          "lastName": "Michalowicz"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
          "firstName": "Michael",
          "lastName": "Jordan"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "twitter",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
          "cities": "59c95a090338d4fe4aea6af8",
          "firstName": "Bartosz",
          "lastName": "Michalski"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```